# Calling function immedietaly at AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am totally newbie to AngularJs.

I have pretty good example of ngClick which is calling a Facebook function.

I would like to change it and programmatically to call registerWithFacebook function after my controller will be ready. What is the way for it?

Here is the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/IgorMinar/Hxbqd/5/

```
    angular.module('HomePageModule', []).service('facebookConnect', function($rootScope) {
        this.askFacebookForAuthentication = function(fail, success) {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function() { $rootScope.$apply(success) });
                } else {
                   $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                     fail('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.')
                   });
                }
            });
        }
});

function ConnectCtrl(facebookConnect, $scope, $resource) {

    $scope.user = {}
    $scope.error = null;

    $scope.registerWithFacebook = function() {
        facebookConnect.askFacebookForAuthentication(
        function(reason) { // fail
            $scope.error = reason;
        }, function(user) { // success
            $scope.user = user
        });
    }

    // Tried this but no success
    // $scope.registerWithFacebook();
}

ConnectCtrl.$inject = ['facebookConnect', '$scope', '$resource'];
```

Thanks

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "page load"? And why does this need to run at that point?

Comment: I am just practicing and would like to call registerWithFacebook manually. By "page load" I meant something like this `$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', registerWithFacebook);` But It could not work

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller I also edited my question for stating what I want better. Thanks.

Comment: where's your `FB.init` ? and btw, your fiddle doesn't include the actual fb sdk script.  Regarding your question, anything that is executed in an angular controller is executed after the app has loaded, which in most cases means, after the dom is ready; so all you have to do is call `$scope.registerWithFacebook()` after you define it

Comment: I have not added all the parts of my question. FB.init section is actually available at Fiddle. `$scope.registerWithFacebook()` has not worked too. Is it possible to make it work for me at my fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the FB library asynchronously, you need to let angular know after it initializes.  Here is one way to do it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YO4duxL1Mh3dwYEEpprV?p=preview